# CSS3 inset box-shadow not working on border

Tags: html-lists, shadow, css

The shadow on the parent `div` doesn't affect the borders of the `li` elements within it. Does anyone know how to solve that issue?

Here's some code: http://jsfiddle.net/ukhgK/2/

CSS:

```
#b {
    box-shadow: inset -6px 0px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
        background-color:#a3a3a3;
    height:100%;
    width:150px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    z-index:9;
    color:white;
    line-height:40px;
    padding-left:6px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    border-bottom:10px solid #828282;
    border-top:10px solid #b8b8b8;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="b">
    <ul>
        <li>Number1</li>
        <li>Number2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got it. Since the inset shadow is part of the background of the div element, you need to set the elements above it transparent so you can see through them.

Fixed code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ukhgK/5/

```
li {
    z-index:9;
    color:white;
    line-height:40px;
    padding-left:6px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    border-bottom:10px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.2);
    border-top:10px solid rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the li's, it is with the ul

One way to solve it is setting a right margin to it:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
margin: 0;
    margin-right: 12px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/ukhgK/4/)

I changed the color of the shadow to make it more visible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want the shadow to cover the border too, this is in my opinion just a workaround. Got another idea?